# "Missing autofillHints attribute"

Tags: android

I have an issue with `Palette -> Text`
When I want to set some view, I receive a message problem `"Missing autofillHints attribute"`
Any suggestions?

Comment: `tools:ignore="Autofill"` is only way to ignore for now.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Perhaps you are using an `EditText`. [**`autofillHints`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:autofillHints) is used in API 26 and above for filling empty `EditText`s and it's actually suggesting which type of content should be placed in there.

Just add :

```
android:autofillHints="username" // the type of content you want
```

To your `EditText` and warning will disappear.

> You do this using the new `android:autofillHints` attribute to tell
>   `autofill` ***what type of content you expect***, and
>   `android:importantForAutofill` to tell `autofill` which views you want (or
>   do not want) to be filled.

**Read:** https://medium.com/@bherbst/getting-androids-autofill-to-work-for-you-21435debea1

**And this:** https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services

---

**Edit:**

You can however set:

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

To the component to tell it is not important to fill and get rid of the error.

Comment: Again errors :(  "Missing accessibility label" "Attribute unused on older version"

Comment: Can I see an screenshot? It should be disappear after that.

Comment: Again errors :( "Missing accessibility label" "Attribute unused on older version"

Comment: I'm new person here, so I can't yet sent pictures :(

Comment: You can actually. Add the picture in your question (use edit button). However, those are just warnings which can be bypassed by adding `tools:targetApi="o"`.

Comment: I changed API level from API 28 to API 25 and it worked!! but I have a question, was it good option to change level?

Comment: It's up to you. However, you could use the latest API and just adding `tools:targetApi="o"` because it is available from API 26 and up so, no need to be worried. It's actually not a good idea to downgrade the API. Those were just **warnings** which could be ignored or bypassed.

Comment: I did as it how you told me and it worked !! thanks a lot and have a nice evening :)

Comment: Note: "importantForAutofill" is only used in API level 26 and higher

Answer (score 113):

#### If you don't want `autofillHints`

**minSdk>=26** .

Should use `android:importantForAutofill=no` if you don't want autofill hint

```
<EditText
        android:importantForAutofill="no"/>
```

**minSdk<26**

Add `android:importantForAutofill` then `tools:targetApi` to make IDE don't this warning about API level

```
<EditText
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        tools:targetApi="o"
 />
```

#### If you want `autofillHints`

Autofill service enable by default even if we don't set `autofillHints` attribute. specify an autofillHints will help autofill service work better like our expection. see [documents here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize#hints)

**minSdk>=26**

- Just need to add `android:autofillHints="{a contant value}"` (eg: `"android:autofillHints="password"`) (use constant from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAutofillHints(java.lang.String...)))

**minSdk<26**, add `tools:targetApi` to make IDE don't this warning

```
    <EditText
            android:autofillHints="emailAddress"
            tools:targetApi="o"/>
```

**Note**

- `autofillHints` and `importantForAutofill` only used in API 26 and higher but we still can use it in API < 26 without crash ([you can see in this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27100238/5381331) (it don't crash but ofcourse it don't have any effect with API < 26)
- `tool:...` just use to make IDE don't warning, it will not effect anything when application running so `tools:ignore="Autofill` don't help you hide autofill hint

Comment: According to the documentation - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAutofillHints(java.lang.String...) - the `android:autoFillHints` constant for an email address is `emailAddress` rather than just `email`.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering this comment was more useful for me than the entire answer. Thanks a ton

Comment: This answer is better structured & more readable than the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

you need to the **strings.xml** file and enable the string text in there, for example:

```
<string name="editText2">Name</string>.
```

then you need to `activity_mail.xml` - and then enable the **autofillhint activity** there, by using:

```
android:hint="@string/editText2"
```

Comment: There isn't a solution for the problem

Answer (score 0):

For me first, I wrote this but had error:

```
<EditText
    android:autofillHints="Name"
    ....../>
```

So I changed it in the form below and worked:

```
<EditText
    android:hint="Name"
    ....../>
```

You can always suppress it if you do not need with:

```
<EditText
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    ....../>
```